# @google/maps request query is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps

I'm currently building a node.js project that will be requesting for places around the world using the google map places API.

Currently, the response given by Google seems to be inconsistent as some query gives result and some don't.

Here's my request line:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?maxprice=4&minprice=1&query=newyork&radius=5000&type=hotel&key=KEY_HERE
```

This line works fine and is able to give me results, but if I were to change New York into something else (Sydney for example) it will, in turn, give me this response

```
{
"html_attributions" : [],
"results" : [],
"status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Sydney request line:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?maxprice=4&minprice=1&query=sydney&radius=5000&type=hotel&key=KEY_HERE
```

I've tried this with some other famous cities and I'm not able to get a consistent result (some works some don't). I've tried reducing the radius and change other options, but nothing seems to work.

and here's my code from the node.js project

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
    key: 'KEY_HERE',
});

googleMapsClient.places({
        query: 'new york',
        radius: 50000,
        minprice: 1,
        maxprice: 4,
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (!err) {
            jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log('response.json: ' + jsonResponse);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If google doesn't have data for your query there's nothing you can do about it. You have to handle the 'ZERO_RESULTS'.

Comment: There are two issues here. Firstly, your calls to Places Text Search are not correct. You are sending an ambiguous query of "Sydney", a radius with no location, and you are using a type of "hotel", which is [not a supported type for the Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types). Your query should be what you are looking for e.g. "hotels in Sydney", and the type should be "lodging", which is supported. Secondly, there is an [existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/76783759) where including `maxprice` and `minprice` in requests may lead to no results

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels%20in%20Sydney&type=lodging&key=YOUR_KEY

Comment: Thanks so much Preston, this seems to be the answer to my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously answered by Preston,

There are two issues here. Firstly, your calls to Places Text Search are not correct. You are sending an ambiguous query of "Sydney", a radius with no location, and you are using a type of "hotel", which is not a supported type for the Places SDK. Your query should be what you are looking for e.g. "hotels in Sydney", and the type should be "lodging", which is supported. Secondly, there is an existing issue where including maxprice and minprice in requests may lead to no results